# How change icon .jar imported scene builder

Tags: javafx

Currently im doing my thesis work, and I'm making a component library with `javafx`.

But im dealing a problem that I wish I could change the icon that puts the tool scene builder imported `.jar`.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: how change the icon of the .jar into the JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0?

Comment: I guess you want to change the icon of the custom control in the scene builder. Currently all custom controls are displayed with a `?`.

Comment: yeah, that's what I do !!!!

Answer (score 0):

In Scene Builder 2.0 icons for custom controls from JAR files are set by `private Collection<LibraryItem> makeLibraryItems(JarReport jarReport)` in the `private LibraryItem makeLibraryItem(Path path)` function. Currently the source for that function is:

```
private Collection<LibraryItem> makeLibraryItems(JarReport jarReport) throws IOException {
    final List<LibraryItem> result = new ArrayList<>();
    final URL iconURL = ImageUtils.getNodeIconURL(null);
    final List<String> excludedItems = library.getFilter();

    for (JarReportEntry e : jarReport.getEntries()) {
        if ((e.getStatus() == JarReportEntry.Status.OK) && e.isNode()) {
            // We filter out items listed in the excluded list, based on canonical name of the class.
            final String canonicalName = e.getKlass().getCanonicalName();
            if (! excludedItems.contains(canonicalName)) {
                final String name = e.getKlass().getSimpleName();
                final String fxmlText = JarExplorer.makeFxmlText(e.getKlass());
                result.add(new LibraryItem(name, UserLibrary.TAG_USER_DEFINED, fxmlText, iconURL, library));
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

As you can see the iconURL is not based on anything supplied by your control's JAR so it is currently not possible to supply an icon. This would require a change to Scene Builder (this could be done after all it's open source).

I know this question is a bit old, but hopefully this helps somebody.